# Converting timestamp value into date inside variant in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to convert timestamp values into date inside a variant column in snowflake.

Below is my table data

```
Id    Json_delta
  
1   {"booking_date": "2022-11-18",  "manufacturing_date": "2022-11-18",  "receipt_date": "2022-11-18"}
2   {"booking_date": "2017-02-24 14:00:00.123","manufacturing_date": "2022-11-18",  "receipt_date": "2022-11-18"}
3   {  "manufacturing_date": "2022-11-18",  "receipt_date": "2022-11-18"}
4   {  "booking_date": null,  "manufacturing_date": "2022-11-18",  "receipt_date": "2022-11-18"}
```

I want to convert booking_date value into date where it is timestamp. I am planning to use below update statement, But struggling to create a where clause in this query

```
update tab set json_delta = OBJECT_INSERT(json_delta,'booking_date',to_date(json_delta:booking_date::varchar),TRUE)
```

Above query will update all the rows. I need help in creating a where clause to filter out rows which have booking_date in timestamp format.

I have tried using a filter `where is_date(json_delta:local_receipt_date) = false`, but its not working.

For the above data, where clause should fetch only the row where Id=2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I need help in creating a where clause to filter out rows which have
> booking_date in timestamp format.

This can be done using [TRY CAST function in snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast).

Like below :

```
WHERE TRY_CAST(json_delta:booking_date AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ) IS NOT NULL;
```

`TRY_CAST` converts a value of one data type into another data type, but returns a NULL value instead of raising an error when the conversion can not be performed.

You can also do it using [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp)

```
WHERE TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_delta:booking_date) IS NOT NULL;
```

`TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP` converts an input expression into a timestamp. If the conversion cannot be performed, it returns a NULL value instead of raising an error).

> Update : to retrieve rows that have booking_id in timestamp format.

```
UPDATE tab 
SET json_delta = OBJECT_INSERT(json_delta, 'booking_date', TO_DATE(json_delta:booking_date::varchar), TRUE)
WHERE CASE WHEN TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(json_delta:booking_date::varchar) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
TRY_CAST and TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP both will fetch rows where booking_id is already in date format. However, I want to retrieve rows that have booking_id in timestamp format.

Comment: Hi Yogesh,
Can you see my updated answer based on your comment ?

Comment: Hi Tushar, I have checked your updated answer. It's still not solving the problem.  Where clause is fetching rows 1 and 2. Ideally, It should fetch only row no 2 because its have booking_date in timestamp format, and only this needs to be converted into a date, rest rows will remain as it is.